# TURN Server use https connection for the admin session

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, turn, coturn

I have installed TURN server. And APACHE is also installed there. SSL Certificates are also installed. The site is running fine where I am typing https://www.domain.com or https://domain.com

But if I type only www.domain.com or domain.com it is saying "TURN Server 
use https connection for the admin session".

All I want, if someone types the URL without HTTPS, it will redirect it to HTTPS URL.

It is a server where TURN Server is also installed ( Repeating it again )

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://br.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828) link can help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The Apache doc recommend [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is it TURN Server independent ?

Comment: Yes, but, In the case of the http-to-https redirection, the use of `RewriteRule` would be appropriate if you don't have access to the main server configuration file, and are obliged to perform this task in a .htaccess file instead.

Comment: Didn't work. It seems port 80 is not accessible by Apache2 anymore. It is now controlled by Turn Server. That's why it is not working.

Comment: Please check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984670/apprtc-with-coturn-stun-turn-server)